# Как задать значение "выбрано" чекбоксу из контроллера в Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

Имеются такие чекбоксы в **blade**:

```
<p><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="roles[]" value="role1">Роль1</p>
<p><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="roles[]" value="role2">Роль2</p>
```

Допустим, в контроллере получаю массив ролей, где имеется **role2**.
Как мне задать в **blade** чекбоксам значение "выбрано", если контроллер, возвращая данный шаблон, знает какая роль у пользователя?

Comment: Выставить атрибут `checked`

Comment: Куда выставить?

Comment: `<input name="" value="" checked />`

Comment: Ну это понятно, допустим вернулся из контроллера значение role2, мне checked его атрибутом @if проверять что-ли?

Comment: Роли только 2? Если да то не заморачивайтесь и добавьте условием `<input ... name="roles[]" value="role2" {{ $data->role === 'role2' ? 'checked': '' }}>`, и для 1 роли аналогично, только соответствие role1

Comment: Ну а как ты хотел без `if` проверять?

Comment: @InDevX Ну или так да.

Comment: @InDevX, я посмотрел и увидел там пример: echo Form::checkbox('name', 'value', true) скорей всего это он. Только как мне это в рамках контроллера Laravel прописать?

Comment: @InDevX разве это работает в последних версиях? Вы привели ссылку на доку для версии 4.2, насколько я знаю, минимум несколько лет это существует как отдельный пакет [Laravel Collective](https://laravelcollective.com)

Comment: @Simon всё верно, просто ТС не пишет версию, попробует - не будет работать - напишет, возможно стоило сразу написать

Comment: Попробовал этим методом: `<input ... name="roles[]" value="role2" {{ $data->role === 'role2' ? 'checked': '' }}>`, всё работает, всем спасибо